# "OK" button text translation in MessageBox - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A `message box` is displayed in the **C#** console application. It's a simple `message box` with a **"OK"** `button`.

My question is whether the **"OK"** text in the `message box` button gets automatically  translated to **german/portuguese** when the `message box` opens in **german/portuguese** OS? Or do we need to add some code logic to get the translated **"OK"** string displayed in the `message box`.

Comment: create a custom form, and use it as `MesssageBox`

Comment: Is your application actually translated into all supported languages of Windows? I ask because on my Dutch system, I occasionally see English programs that don't have Dutch translations, yet do use Dutch button captions. That doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MessageBox.Show calls a native API function which shows a standard Windows dialog box.
The buttons will appear in the current system UI language automatically.

If you want to localize them to some other language, you'll have to implement your own MessageBox-like class.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand it correctly, the messagebox.show() method calls the native system OS API, which automatically translates "OK" text in the button (default text) to its respective OS language text. Hence we need not add logic to ensure "OK" text displays appropriately with chinese text in chinese OS. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

No the Message box will display **OK** even if you open the message box in any other language. However you could write your own Message Box to display that result. I did come across this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox), that seem to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Rohan. By "other language", did you mean OS with other language?. I have not written any code for displaying "OK" text in the message box button. It's a simple MessageBox.Show("body","heading"). "OK" button displays automatically. So if I re-iterate my question, will the "OK" display in chinese when the message box is displayed in chinese OS?

Comment: Firstly i would say that The buttons are in the language of the system user interface. So yes the "OK" will display in chinese when the message box is displayed inan OS who has their language set to chinese.